# How to render polymorphic comment partial in feed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller, polymorphic-associations

I created a feed following http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity?view=asciicast.

In that feed I'd like it to say,

> **"User Name"** added/updated value **"Value Name"** *with the comment **"Comment Content"***.

This partial creates the **"Value Name"** part:

- views/public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb

```html
added value
<% if activity.trackable %>
  <b><%= link_to activity.trackable.name, activity.trackable %></b>
<% else %>
  which has since been removed 
<% end %>
```

This partial creates the **"Comment Content"** part:

- views/public_activity/valuation/_create.html.erb

```html
with the comment
<% if activity.trackable %>
  <%= link_to activity.trackable.content %>
<% else %>
  which has since been removed 
<% end %>
```

If I add name or content to either one of the partials I am given an `undefined method` error message. What code would I need to add to their controllers or application controller to make something like this work?

Ideally, *with the comment "Comment Content".* would only be generated in instances where a comment is created so that, *with the comment*, wouldn't be left hanging.

```html
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :load_commentable
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

 def index
  @comments = @commentable.comments
 end

 def new
  @comment = @commentable.comments.new
 end

 def create
  @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
  if @comment.save
   @comment.create_activity :create, owner: current_user
   redirect_to @commentable, notice: "comment created."
  else
   render :new
  end
 end

 def edit
  @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
  @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
  if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
   redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment was updated."
  else
   render :edit
  end
 end

 def destroy
  @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy
  @comment.create_activity :destroy, owner: current_user
  redirect_to @commentable, notice: "comment destroyed."
 end

private
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

 def load_commentable
  resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
  @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
 end

 def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :commentable)
 end
end
```

```html
class ValuationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_valuation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @valuations = Valuation.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @valuations = Valuation.order('RANDOM()')
    end
  end

  def show
    @valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @valuation
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def new
    @valuation = current_user.valuations.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @valuation = current_user.valuations.build(valuation_params)
    if @valuation.save
      redirect_to @valuation, notice: 'Value was successfully created'
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
  end
end

  def update
    if @valuation.update(valuation_params)
      redirect_to @valuation, notice: 'Value was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @valuation.destroy
    redirect_to valuations_url
  end

  private
    def set_valuation
      @valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @valuation = current_user.valuations.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to valuations_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this valuation" if @valuation.nil?
    end

    def valuation_params
      params.require(:valuation).permit(:name, :private_submit, :tag_list, :content, :commentable, :comment)
    end
end
```

```html
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include PublicActivity::StoreController
  #before_action :load_todays_habits
  before_action :set_top_3_goals
  before_action :randomize_value
  before_action :set_stats
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper

  def set_top_3_goals
    @top_3_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished.top_3 if current_user
  end

  def randomize_value
    @sidebarvaluations = current_user.valuations.randomize if current_user
  end

  def set_stats
    @quantifieds = Quantified.joins(:results).all
    @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged if current_user
    @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance if current_user
  end

    hide_action :current_user

  private 

  #def load_todays_habits
  #  @user_tags = current_user.habits.committed_for_today.tag_counts if current_user
  #  @all_tags  = Habit.committed_for_today.tag_counts if current_user
  #end

  # Confirms a logged-in user.
  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end
end
```

**Thank you so much for your time.**